# WatiN and Internet Explorer 7

Tags: c#, unit-testing, internet-explorer-7, watin

I'm using the WatiN, but when i developed my application test, i was using the Internet Explorer 6, but recently, the browser is updated to Internet Explorer 7.

My appliations test can't start the browser.

Can I solve this trouble?

Thanks in advance.

Daniel Benevides

Comment: What version of WatiN are you using? And are you running Visual Studio as Administrator? The latter has solved some random problems for me from time to time.

Comment: Why are you still using IE7 and IE6, neither are going to be supported in the version, you should be using IE8 and IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update to the latest version of WatiN, version 2.1, that one works with Internet Explorer 9.

Check out the notes at http://watin.org/documentation/release-2-1-0-1196/.